# Angular how to update UI for ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm have project write by Angular
But in my component using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
I update properti to new value from storage but UI not update
So anyonce can help me solve this problem (can use Observeble for pipeAsync)
Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZtI4.png)

Comment: maybe you can create a stackblitz?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3686898)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With OnPush, you need to tell Angular Component to detect change and update outside the event.
With your case I think
`this.cdRef.markForCheck(); // Tell Angular to run detectChanges on this component`
Might work.

Comment: i current using  async pipe observeble to resolved